# Wildfly throws exception when client closes http web request connection

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, ioexception, undertow

We have an app that uses a Wildfly server as its rest service.  In the app, a database call which updates points on a map.  Eevery time a new call is made the app cancels the previous HTTP web request and makes a new one, which is throwing an error in Wildfly, and a possible a memory leak

Is there something that can be done in the standalone or should i be looking somewhere else?

```
[0m[31m10:26:26,158 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ws/rest/app-bridge/north/33.216635/west/-117.331112/south/32.618437/east/-116.857564/pointsInMap: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY003770: Response is committed, can't handle exception
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:152)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doWrap(SslConduit.java:795)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.write(SslConduit.java:348)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:638)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:169)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:237)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:1979)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:600)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.close(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.CommitHeaderOutputStream.close(CommitHeaderOutputStream.java:87)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.DelegatingOutputStream.close(DelegatingOutputStream.java:60)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.writeTo(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:131)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(GZIPEncodingInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:466)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have already solved your problems, but I think it's worth mentioning here an answer I found for a similar problem.

Problem may be in the moment of serializing the response data, where the outputStream is closed. In this publication you will find more details.
[UnhandledException throw from SynchronousDispatcher writeException not goto ExceptionMapper](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1532)